# Arduino Firebase ESP8266 Connection

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am working on a project that needs data to be stored in cloud db so that I can access the data in a mobile application. For database I have considered Firebase. I am following the following [link](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/electropeak/connecting-arduino-to-firebase-to-send-receive-data-cd8805). But when i try to install the libraries i am getting `No such file or directory found` errors for `memory`, `queue`, `Firebase.h`, `vector`, `functional`, `utilities` (not all but different packages shows different errors). I tried downloading different packages from github. But still had the errors. Where can I find the correct working program? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sketches in the linked tutorial are missing the includes. The wiring is missing  a wire.

Comment: @Juraj Can you please tell me what are the additional wiring that are required?

Comment: the tutorial is useless. forget about it. the sketch is for the esp8266, not for Uno so there should be no Uno. the Uno is used for power and the USB chip, but nothing about it is explained. there are no links to resources, nothing about esp8266 arduino core package etc

Comment: @Juraj Actually I need an arduino uno because the other part of the project receives data from bluetooth sensor (HC-05), and i need to store the received data in the database. Or is there any way to do this without Arduino Uno. (I am completely new to Arduino Programming. So please dont mind if my questions are silly).

Comment: you could not use two serial devices on one Uno..use an esp8266 development board with USB and power regulator. I recommend Wemos D1 Mini. https://docs.wemos.cc/en/latest/d1/d1_mini.html

Comment: @Juraj My project is to scan the available Bluetooth signals available and to upload them to the database. For scanning available Bluetooth signals I am using HC-05 AT command (AT+INQ). I have stored the read signals into a string in Arduino Uno. Can you please help me on how to continue further to upload this data to the database?

Comment: it is not simple. there is no arduino library for Firebase on Uno. so you must do the communication with Firebase in a sketch on esp8266 and code the data exchange over SoftwareSerial between Uno and esp-01

Answer (score 1):

The usual Firebase library for esp8266 is https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino.

And there is some new Firebase library in Library Manager in IDE. The "More info" link leads to https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266

[image]

Comment: I am still getting this error.
```Firebase.h:25:10: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory

 #include <memory>

          ^~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.```

Comment: did you install the esp8266 boards package? the library is for esp8266, you can't compile it for Uno